How to Modify/remove response headers conditionally/dynamically based on actual value of response header. (Chrome Extension MV3)
I want to block request/ modify response headers based on the actual response headers I receive using declarativeNetRequest in chrome MV3.
In MV2 it was simple as we could do it in a blocking way using .webRequest.onHeadersReceived . But I don't see how that is possible in MV3 , given there's nothing dynamic possible in the pre defined rules of declarativeNetRequest.
Note : Any kind of urlFilter/regexFilter based solution will not serve. my needs

It's not yet implemented, see https://crbug.com/40727004.
